# Create inter linked drop-downs in excel files using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlrd

I am working to write python script using xlsxwriter package. I have already written the script but reached at a point where I am unable to move ahead.

Let me explain what I want to achieve:-

I have created two sheets in excel file using python. Both the sheets have one drop-down with the same values. I wants to create a one to one linking between the both. That means change of value in one drop-down should automatically change the value in the drop-down present on the another sheet. Vice versa will also be applicable.

Example :-

When I select value A in dropdown Shee1 then value in dropdown B of sheet2 should automatically set to B. Same process should work when I change value in sheet2 drop-down.

I have already tried to get it implemented using xlsxwriter, xlrd and some other well known packages, but haven't found any solid reference that can solve my problem.So, I need someone assistance to find a workable solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Leaving Python and XlsxWriter aside, how would you do this in Excel?

Comment: That's a case. I tried to do the same using Excel but haven't found any way. Since I more focused to create using python script, so I haven't focused much on excel side. Anyways, what do you say on it? Is it possible? @jmcnamara

Comment: I don't know. It would probably require VBA to implement. And you would need to be careful not to generate an infinite loop of A updating B updating A. Either way once you figure out how to do it in Excel you can then figure out how/if you can do it with Python.